# how to read image i get from server as a buffer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

this is the code from server:

```js
router.get('/vacation/pic', function(req, res, next) { 
 fs.readFile('./public/picters/avatar-1566053205516', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.write(data);
  console.log(data);
  res.end();
});
});
```

this is from frontend where i get the image:

```js
onGetpics: () =>{ axios.get('http://localhost:3000/vacation/pic', {
    })
    .then(res => {
     dispatch({ type: "GET_PICS",value:res.data})
    })  
    }
  };
```

[this is how i get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zunZu.png)

[and this is how it sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTpAn.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is construct a data URL from your image data that looks like this:

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOV...">`

I'm still  a little uncertain looking at what you've posted how exactly you get the data (I see you have a variable named `pics` for instance, which confuses me as to whether that's the data for a single image, or multiple images all mushed together), but it does look like the binary image data is delivered in a string, so the function `btoa()`, which turns binary data into base64 format, will help.

The basic logic would look like sort of like this:

```
const imageElem = document.getElementById('image-id'); // Could be a querySelector as well

// Assuming PNG image
imageElem.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa(theImageDataAsString);
```